# Parsing special cases

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, peg, ll-grammar, lr-grammar

If I understand correctly, parsing turns a sequence of symbols into a tree. My question is, is it possible to use some standard procedure (LR, LL, PEG, ..?) to parse the following two examples or is it necessary to write a specialized parser by hand?

1. Python source code, i.e. the whitespace-indented blocks

I think I read somewhere that the parser keeps track of the number of leading spaces, and pretends to replace them with curly brackets to delimitate the blocks. Is it fundamentally required because the standard parsing techniques are not powerful enough or is it for performance reasons?

2. PNG image format, where a block starts with a header and block size, after which there is the content of the block

The content could contain bytes which resemble some header so it is necessary to "know" that the next x bytes are not to be "parsed", i.e. they should be skipped. How to express this, say, with PEG? In other words, the "closing bracket" is represented by the length of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the examples in the question are context-free, so strictly speaking they cannot be parsed with context-free grammars. But in practical terms, they are both pretty easy to parse.

The python algorithm is well-described in the Python [reference manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) (although you need to read that in context.) What's described there is a pre-processing step in which whitespace at the beginning of a line is systematically replaced with `INDENT` and `DEDENT` tokens.

To clarify: It's not really a preprocessing step, and it's important to observe that it happens *after* implicit and explicit line joining. (There are previous sections in the reference manual which describe these procedures.) In particular, lines are implicitly joined inside parentheses, braces and brackets, so the process is intertwined with parsing.

In practical terms, both the line-joining and indentation algorithms can be accomplished programmatically; typically, these would be done inside a custom scanner (tokenizer) which maintains both a stack of parentheses and indent levels. The token stream can then be parsed with normal context-free algorithms, but the tokenizer -- although it might *use* regular expressions -- needs context-sensitive logic (counting spaces, for example). [Note 1]

Similarly, formats which contain explicit sizes (such as most serialization formats, including PNG files, Google protobufs, and HTTP chunked encoding) are not context-free, but are obviously easy to tokenize since the tokenizer simply has to read the length and then read that many bytes.

There are a variety of context-sensitive formalisms, and these definitely have their uses, but in practical parsing the most common strategy is to use a Turing-equivalent formalism (such as any programming language, possibly augmented with a scanner-generator like `flex`) for the tokenizer and a context-free formalism for the parser. [Note 2]

---

**Notes:**

1. It may not be immediately obvious that Python indenting is not context-free, since context-free grammars can accept some categories of agreement. For example, `{ωω-1 | ω∈Σ*}` (the language of all even-length palindromes) is context-free, as is `{anbn}`.

   However, these examples can't be extended, because the only count-agreement possible in a context-free language is bracketing. So while palindromes are context-free (you can implement the check with a single stack), the apparently very similar `{ωω | ω∈Σ*}` is not, and neither is `{anbncn}`
2. One such formalism is back-references in "regular" expressions, which might be available in some PEG implementation. Back-references allow the expression of a variety of context-sensitive languages, but do not allow the expression of all context-free languages. Unfortunately, regular expressions with back-references really suck in practice, because the problem of determining whether a string matches a regex with back-references is NP complete. You might find [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/where-do-most-regex-implementations-fall-on-the-complexity-scale) on a sister SE site interesting. (And you might want to reformulate your question in a way that could be asked on that site, http://cs.stackexchange.com.)

Answer (score 0):

As a practical matter, almost all parser construction requires some clever hacks around the edges to overcome the limitations of the parsing machinery.

Pure context free parsers can't do Python; all the parser technologies you have listed are weaker than pure-context free, so they can't do it either. A hack in the lexer to keep track of indentation, and generate  INDENT/DEDENT tokens, turns the indenting problem into explicit "parentheses", which are easily handled by context-free parsers.

Most binary files can't be processed either, as they usually contain, somewhere, a list of length N, where N is provided before the list body is encountered (this is kind of the example you gave).  Again, you can get around this, with a more complicated hack; something must keep a stack of nested list lengths, and the parser has to signal when it moves from one list element to the next.  The top-most length counter gets decremented, and the parser gets back a signal "reduce" or "shift".    Other more complex linked structures are generally pretty hard to parse this way.  Getting the parser to cooperate this way isn't always easy.